# Script export information

Tags: php, sql, prestashop

I realize a script of export of information between two dates and I meet a small difficulty. Here is the scenario of my script:

- First column: Exporting sponsor names
- Second column: Export the number of godchildren total godfathers
- Third column: Total sales of the sponsors that we generate
- Fourth column: Export the number of new referrals in the selected date
- Fifth column: Sales turnover of new referrals in the selected date

My script works perfectly but I would like to add to my condition this:

- If a godson register on 01/01 and order on 02/02
- When I ask for an export between the 01/01 to the 30/01 it would be necessary that in my export I find in the column "new godson" = 1 but on the other hand I do not want to go up the turnover of this godson because it is outside export dates.

Here is the current code:

```
$filename = $this->l('export_perfs');
            $header = array('Ambassadrice:Nom/Prénom', 'Nb Filleul','CA Filleul (total)','Nvx Filleul', 'CA Nvx Filleul');


            // Récupére le nombre de filleuls total et le CA total
            $sql1 = Db::getInstance()->executeS("
            SELECT CONCAT(amb.firstname, ' ', amb.lastname) AS NomPrénom, rs.id_sponsor, c.id_customer, SUM(o.total_products_wt + o.total_shipping) AS CA, c.date_add AS dateFilleul, o.date_add AS dateOrder
            FROM `"._DB_PREFIX_."rewards_sponsorship` rs
            LEFT JOIN `"._DB_PREFIX_."customer` c ON  rs.id_customer = c.id_customer
            LEFT JOIN `"._DB_PREFIX_."customer` amb ON  rs.id_sponsor = amb.id_customer
            LEFT JOIN `"._DB_PREFIX_."orders` o ON(c.id_customer = o.id_customer)
            GROUP BY rs.id_customer");

            $lines = array();
            foreach ($sql1 as $row) {
                $id_sponsor = $row['id_sponsor'];

                $lines[$id_sponsor]['ambassadrice'] = $row['NomPrénom'];
                $lines[$id_sponsor]['totalCa'] += $row['CA'];
                $lines[$id_sponsor]['nbFilleul']++;

                $dateInscriptionFilleul = $row['dateFilleul'];
                $dateOrder = $row['dateOrder'];

                if($dateInscriptionFilleul > $date_from .' 00:00:00' && $dateInscriptionFilleul < $date_to.' 23:59:59' && $dateOrder > $date_from.' 00:00:00' && $dateOrder < $date_to.' 23:59:59') {
                    $lines[$id_sponsor]['nbFilleulNew']++;
                    $lines[$id_sponsor]['totalCaNew'] += $row['CA'];
                }

            }

            $results = [];
            foreach ($lines as $id_sponsor => $data) {
                $results[]  = array(
                    $data['ambassadrice'],
                    $data['nbFilleul'],
                    $data['totalCa'],
                    isset($data['nbFilleulNew'])?$data['nbFilleulNew']:0,
                    isset($data['totalCaNew'])?$data['totalCaNew']:0,
                );
            }

            return $this->generateCSV($results, $header, $filename);

            break;
```

Do you have an idea how to do this?

Thank you for your help